# How do you do "while(choice not in operation)" in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, while-loop

I was trying to make a calculator in C++ and compress it as well as I could. I'm not sure how to translate "while choice not in operation" from Python to C++.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    string operation[] = { "+","-","/","*" };
    string choice;

    int main(){
        while (choice not in operation) {
        cout << "Enter the operation that you want to use(/,*,+,-): ";
        cin >> operation;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) might help

Answer (score 4):

This is idiomatic C++, efficient, and fairly concise:

```
while (find(begin(operation), end(operation), choice) == end(operation))
```